Safe way to operate on a sequence filter
THe intention in the code below is to get the name of the student whose id is equal to 30
class Person(name: String ,  id : Int)
val people = Seq(
    Person("Emily", 10),
    Person("Hannah", 20),
    Person("Mercedes", 30)
)
val selected = people.filter(_.id == 30).headOption.map(_.name).get

While this code would work - it has several points of failure.
What is the recommended way to write this safe and clean.

The main point of failure I see is that .get could fail if headOption is None. What would you want the value of selected to be if there is no Person in the Seq with ID 30? If you want to be robust to this case, you probably want selected to be Option[String] rather than String. If that's what you want, just omit the .get. Do you have other concerns, besides this failure if none are selected? If you do want to unwrap to String, consider using a match against the filtered Seq rather than .get. Then sdd a default case to handle the potential failure any way you like.

You can use find then you have two options:

Set a default value if nothing is selected

val selected = people.find(_.id == 30).map(_.name).getOrElse("No Selection")
println("Selected : " + selected)


Using match to process the returned Option

people.find(_.id == 30).map(_.name) match {
    case Some(selected) => println("Selected : " + selected)
    case None => println("No Selection")
}

Both should result in:
Selected : Mercedes

